# updating a value of a nested object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nested-object

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const instructorSchema = new Schema(
  {
    instructorID: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      minlength: 3,
    },

    name: { type: String, required: true },

    dob: { type: Date, required: true },

    gender: { type: String, required: true },

    address: { type: String, required: true },

    phone: { type: Number, required: true },

    email: { type: String, required: true },

    password: { type: String, required: true },

    userRequests: [
      {
        userProfile: { type: String },
        userName: { type: String },
        weight: { type: String },
        height: { type: String },
        gender: { type: String },
        requirement: { type: String },
        assigned: { type: String },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true, //it will automatically create fields when it is created or modified
  }
);

const Instructor = mongoose.model("Instructor", instructorSchema);

module.exports = Instructor;
```

I want to update the value of requirement property for a given userProfile(this is an obejectID)and given instructor(instructorID). Can someone help me with a nodejs route.

I checked this on stackoverflow but I didn't find an answer for this.

Comment: What do you mean by node.js route? It's a schema for mongoDB and you have to update a value in sub-document, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: its a schema...

Comment: What are you looking for? What have your tried?